# Can't add duplicate data to sql table, even though no PK or Unique value enabled

Tags: php, mysql, file, insert

I have a txt file which has 1 line of `\t` data in it, the data in the file is updated via a loop and in this loop at the end it is placed into a table. The current data I am working with has 24 columns and 25 lines, and it enters it all fine apart from the 2 lines which have identical first values; of these only 1 is entered.

I do not have anything set as Primary Key or Unique Value enabled, yet it just doesn't enter the line with identical first value, even values 3,4 and 5 are all the same as well.

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn);

mysql_query ("TRUNCATE TABLE imported_orders"); 

$lines = file('F:/xamptest/htdocs/UniProject/upload/Amazon output.txt');
$lineCount = count($lines);
for ($arrayCounter=0; $lineCount>$arrayCounter; $arrayCounter++)
{
    $lineEx = explode("\t", $lines[$arrayCounter]);         
    $lineEx[2] = substr($lineEx[2], 0, -15); 
    $lineEx[3] = substr($lineEx[3], 0, -15);
    $lineEx[4] = substr($lineEx[4], 0, -15);
    $lineEx[5] = substr($lineEx[5], 0, -15);        
    $arri = implode("\t",$lineEx);      
    file_put_contents('upload/ImportLine.txt', $arri);
    $r = mysql_query ("LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:/xamptest/htdocs/UniProject/upload/ImportLine.txt' INTO TABLE imported_orders FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'", $conn);        
    echo "Array Counter Loop: ".$arrayCounter." Order ID: ".$lineEx[0]."<br>";              
}   
echo "<br>WLoop has ran: ".$arrayCounter." Times";  
?>
```

Even using a only a loop and the single line file on it's own it just adds one row, I tried adding a first column as a PK Auto Increment, which doesn't work how I assumed it would and tries to put the first value from the file in it -.-'

This has had me stumped for days, as there is no apparent reason for it not to work, ideally I'd like to `INSERT` the imploded array value directly and define the values by `\t` like I do now, but from what I've searched to doesn't seem to be possible.

EDIT: Made value 1 and 2 a composite primary key, worked, now it doesn't. Just ran it again, for 6th time and now only enters 24 rows again -.-'

Sorry for my clear lack of experience with php and sql.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you give us an example of your table layout with demo data

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Made first and second values a Composite Primary Key which has seemed to made this work.
Still not sure why it initially wouldn't work as the first column wasn't set to PK or anything, but I'm just glad it works now. Thanks for willing to help though :)

Comment: It seems you figured it your original question, but why are you running the INSERT command inside the loop?  You should take advantage of the database being able to insert all the data in one query and it will run significantly quicker than inserting one row at a time.

Comment: Wouldn't that require me to list all 24 column names and the array, so column1, column2 etc VALUES array[0], array[1] etc. since I need to loop it to alter some of the values anyway thought this might be neater. If I could say enter from this string, values determined by \t that'd be great, but seems you can't.
Also I haven't fixed the issue, was entering all rows, now it isn't I HAVEN'T CHANGED ANYTHING :'(